# How Should I Be Maintaining My Manually Installed Apps?

Tags: apt, software-installation

I am used to using apt to install and upgrade my applications. To an extent, I'm relying on the repositiories I use to be sane and thus keep my machine in a good state.

What is best-practice for keeping my manually installed application up-to-date? Is it simply a case of regularly checking the application's website for new releases and patches?